# How can I search product by its category in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, search, categories

I am using **Magento 1.9.1.0**. Here I want `search` product by its `category`. Currently I have three `categories`.

```
Furniture 
Kitchen Accessories 
Electronics
```

Each `category` have their own products. Now in `search field` I type one of my `category` (for example Furniture). But it not gives proper result. It should show all product from that specified category (here Furniture). Unfortunately this gives some products from same category and some from other category.

In `magento` the `attribute` like `Name`, `Description`, `SKU` etc can make searchable. And these work good.

So my question is How can I search product by its category ??

Please Help me.....

Comment: Check if you need to reindex fullcategorysearch: cd root/shell php indexer.php --reindex catalogsearch_fulltext

Answer (score 0):

Follow the step by step procedure. http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/search_and_advanced_search/how_to_add_search_by_category_to_advanced_search